# Can SiriKit be used to order coffee?

Tags: ios, iphone, sirikit

I have an app where user can order coffee. 
I read the following article about the basic domains that SiriKit supports -
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sirikit

Can SiriKit be customised so that i can allow user to order coffee from my app using Siri?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can with iOS 12 ; if you use "Siri Shortcuts"

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sirikit/donating_shortcuts

You need to :

- Create a custom intent (here, the order type should correspond with what you want to do)
- Donate the intent when the user perform an action within your app (when he orders a coffee.
- Handle an intent when the app is opened, and/or with an Extension that handle the request.

For more informations, look at the wwdc videos about Siri Shortcuts :

https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/211/

https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/214/